# Using custom HTML Tags

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

In my HTML I was curious if it was semantically correct to use unique identifiers such as `<toys>` rather than an `<h1>`. For example:

I wanted to have:

```html
<toys class="grid_4 push_2">&nbsp;</toys>
```

With the CSS:

```css
toys {
  background: url("toys.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  width: 181px;
  height: 93px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

I currently have:

```html
<h1 class="grid_4 push_2">&nbsp;</h1>
```

With the CSS:

```css
h1.push_2 {
  background: url("toys.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  width: 181px;
  height: 93px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Is the use of unique identifiers like `<toys>` semantically correct?

Comment: bigger questions about maintenance aside, if it renders correctly for your target audience, it's valid and semantically correct html.

Comment: With a components approach, yes it is (take for instance React and AngularJs components). However I wouldn't recomend it for general use (ie, just throwing new tags in the wind without a concept to support it)

Comment: your custom tag (element) must not name "toys", rather <the-toys> to avoid collision with future standard naming your custom element name must contain hyphen ( https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#custom-element-conformance );

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is best to avoid using custom tags, as you never know when those tags may become standardized, and have special usage in the future.

The best thing to do for your example, if you want to avoid using the header tags, is the following:

```
<div class="toys grid_4 push_2">&nbsp</div>

.toys {
    background: url("toys.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width: 181px;
    height: 93px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

**In addition:**

If you do not use standard html tags when designing pages, they will not appear in any organized manner when styles are disabled. This is not a problem, going forward, but if for any reason you needed to view a list of "toys" without styles, you had be out of luck unless you use `<ul>` or `<ol>` with `<li>` tags.

***UPDATE:***

As Flimzy pointed out in the comments, custom HTML elements now have their own W3C specification. However, they are not yet fully supported.

- Specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/
- Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements

Comment: Thanks for that. You clarified the issues that might crop up as a result of using custom html tags.

Comment: so I ask.. what is the point of having tags at all? shouldn't they provide semantic meaning? Funny that XHTML stands for EXTENSIBLE HTML and yet everyone always freaked when you extended it and your markup didnt validate.

Comment: I don't know any great web developers who think XHTML is better than standard, properly formatted, closed-tag HTML. In fact, I'm sure a lot of new developers think XHTML stands for XML-HTML, in that it adheres more closely to XML standards than previous HTML standards. To answer your question, tags do in fact provide semantic meaning. An HTML document is a *view* of some data. It is not the data itself. Therefore, the tags provide semantic meaning for the way in which they display the data they represent. "div" means division, "p" means paragraph, "section" means section, etc.

Comment: By the same logic I should avoid using functions and variables in C, because I never know when those symbols might become reserved words in future.  I doubt that "toys" will ever be an HTML standard tag, and if it is we may hope that a proactive and capable web master will find it easy to `s/toys/my-toys/g`.  Using and styling custom tags can greatly simplify and clarify markup.

Comment: I think my same argument may apply in C, but in reverse. Language and library designers need to use caution when adding new methods at a global namespace, because users of that language are expected to write methods on top of what is given. Adding a commonly named method without good reason will break the build. It's also worth pointing out that users of the language would be required to opt-in to the new language features. On the web, your site will break when a user gets the latest version of chrome if you just happened to use a tag chrome wanted to experiment with.

Comment: `It is best to avoid using custom tags, as you never know when those tags may become standardized...` this (and thus most of the rest of this answer) is now obsolete advice, as custom tags are explicitly allowed, and using a '-' in the name guarantees they will never become standardized.

Comment: Custom tags are actually a best practice.

Answer (score 48):

Most of these responses are good general advice, but not proper answers to the question, which I think is perfectly legitimate.

HTML5 is already a moving target; browsers implement specs and innovate at different paces. There is no single thing called "valid HTML", at least not that is worth using. If you are building a public page for every person and bot/crawler on the planet, then you already either have to A) detect the client and customize accordingly, for complex/advanced pages or B) make it really, really simple and plain. If, on the other hand, you're putting it on a LAN or hiding it behind a login wall or developing on the cutting edge and plan for frequent updates anyway, then you should feel free to innovate a bit, with discretion. Browser devs and spec writers cater to their needs, you can do the same.

So, if you want a custom tag, choose carefully (here I will point out that the odds that  would ever become part of a formal spec of browser implementation are totally negligible), then go for it. To make your CSS work in IE, though, you will have to do as html5shim does and call document.createElement('toys') in your javascript.

I should also add that custom elements are getting their own standards and support, but the consensus currently is that they all should have a '-' in the name. So I would recommend something like 'x-toys' or 'my-toys' instead of just 'toys'.  Personally, i'm not thrilled with the convention, but I understand the reasons.

Comment: Great answer, especially the bit about *the createElement()* call for Internet Explorer browsers.

Comment: Quote: "Tags contain a tag name, giving the element's name. HTML elements all have names that only use characters in the range U+0030 DIGIT ZERO (0) to U+0039 DIGIT NINE (9), U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+007A LATIN SMALL LETTER Z, and U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to U+005A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z. In the HTML syntax, tag names, even those for foreign elements, may be written with any mix of lower- and uppercase letters that, when converted to all-lowercase, matches the element's tag name; tag names are case-insensitive. "
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#elements-0

Comment: It seems like the minus sign is not officially allowed. It might work in some browsers though.

Comment: Just `toys-` is fine, as W3C themselves are using `<c->` for code highlighting.

Answer (score 7):

You certainly *can*; however, it's generally **not a good idea** to do so. In many ways HTML5 is moving to something like that but genericized; having specific tags, while supported can have very different results among different browsers.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE (because all the answers are old):

As of Web components API gets implemented in every major browser, in my opinion, you can't avoid using custom tags in the future. I think Web Components will easily become mainstream. The whole theory is built on it: Custom tags, custom attributes custom JS attached to these elements.

So what i say: it isn't a bad thing to use your own tags nowadays but you still need to consider SEO related building.

Answer (score 2):

Surely if you define a tag and also define within your stylesheet what it should do, that should tie it up? Even if your new tag later becomes standardised, your stylesheet will override the standard - after all that is what stylesheets are for.

For example, I often need to control line breaks on my pages. Rather than use a clumsy

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">bla bla bla</span>
```

every time, I enclose my non-broken text within my own  tags and define in my stylesheet:

```
nbr {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

so

```
<p> This is some text. <nbr>This is some more text.</nbr></p>
```

will appear on one line if there's room, otherwise the second sentence will appear on the next line.  Or, to be precise, in all browsers except old versions of IE.  To be cast iron, I added the following to each page [head] section (in Wordpress, only need to add to the theme's header.php):-

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script> document.createElement('nbr'); </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. "Even if your new tag later becomes standardised, your stylesheet will override the standard" is very naive. As a real-world example, let's take the `<picture>` element. If you only have something like `white-space:nowrap` in your stylesheet, you will _not_ override all the default styles of this element, and your document will break horribly in newer browsers that support it. So don't do this. Either use the recommended naming protocol for elements you design yourself (i.e. with a dash, `<n-br>`), or put them in a namespace of your own choosing (`<my:nbr>`).

Comment: I agree I do this for a "layout" tag that I like to have specific properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be semantically correct.

However, it's invalid syntax as HTML has a defined set of tags.

You can get around that in some browsers.

That said, what's the benefit of doing that? It really would only benefit the person that has to maintain the source code.

FYI, what you are proposing is pretty much what XML is.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @superUntiled, you should make good use of the CSS selectors (classes and IDs). So if you have an object of type "toy", you should create a class for that object. Then you could select all your `cars` using CSS just using the selector `.toy`.

Something like this:

```
<style>
.toy {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<p class="toy">My little car</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with the original poster that custom elements could be a better way than CSS classes and IDs.  For example I have a friend who manages his inventory and content for his website in Google Sheets.  The google sheets array output is just plain text.  (The frontend HTML uses JS to retrieve content from GSheets). Therefore, I set custom tags, such as `<sale>`, to change font color and style so my friend, who doesn't know coding, can simply insert those tags into the google sheet to customize the font.  It's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If your doctype is set to XHTML, you should be fine. But it's generally not valid for HTML doctypes.

Comment: XHTML is old style. Check up on HTML5 specs.

Comment: @BerggreenDK: I understand that and never did recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to make up your own tags.

The HTML tags are defined in the HTML specification.

In stead of:

```
<h1 class="grid_4 push_2">&nbsp</h1>
```

You should do something like:

```
<h1 class="toys">&nbsp</h1>
```

However you can make up you own tags if XML.

But please note that not all browser support your tag and you won't be able to style them using CSS.

Same thing is happening with new [HTML5 tags](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/08/how-to-make-ie6-to-style-html-5-tags.html)