# Is it okay to use custom tags instead of <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have some HTML with CSS and one instance where I used a custom HTML tag instead of `<p>` it shows up and my CSS picks up the tag and another where it fails to show the text. If I replace 
`<title>Layout Controls</title>` with `<p>Layout Controls</p>` it shows up.

I've put a [demo up](http://jsfiddle.net/wideEyedPupil/McEqh/) on JSfiddle. THe JS works in my browser and Coda2 but not in JS fiddle. I'm probably doing something wrong as far as fiddle is concerned too if anyone can point out what that is to me.

If there are any best-practice comments people care to make that's fine by me too, here to learn.

```
<body>   
  <div class="input_group_box">
    <title>Layout Controls</title><br />
    <sub-title>X-Position</sub-title><br />
    <input id="/layout/1/slider" class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="-1" max="1" step="0.001" onclick="bind('/layout/1', 'slider', parseInt(this.value*1000)/1000)" />
    <input id="/layout/1/number" class="number-box"    type="number" value="0" min="-1" max="1" step="0.01" onclick="bind('/layout/1', 'number', parseFloat(this.value))" /><br />    
   </div>
</body>
```

---

Anybody no why my Javascript isn't binding the two inputs in the demo. Could it be I need to  change the JSFiddle load settings I'm in the dark a bit with that.

Comment: `title` tag is for setting page's title and it doesn't matter where it's used or what CSS rules applied on it!

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with using custom tags, see e.g. [Using custom HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags). They would make coding a little easier, but mostly it’s not a good idea. Use classes instead, such as `<div class=sub-title>...</div>`. But if something is a heading, consider using heading markup for it, like `h2` and `h3`. For form fields, you could use `legend` inside a `fieldset`, too.

The `title` element is a different case, since it has always been defined in HTML and has a special role and processing. It is allowed in the `head` part only. If you put it inside the `body`, the effect depends on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

`<title>` is MTML5  tag, not custom tag.

Try this on it's CSS. It will be fine:

```
title {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Bold, sans-serif;  

    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `<title>` tag is reserved for page title and you should not be using it for any other purpose...