# Is their anyway to add custom tags in HTML

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using custom HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags)

is their an easy way to add custom tags in HTML , I'm looking at some cool filters that I'd only like to apply to certain parts of my web page .

Comment: Take one step back from "I need custom HTML tags to do <this>" and restate your question as "I'm trying to do <this>" with more details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'cool filters', but I dont think you'd need custom HTML tags for them.

Comment: I'd like to add filters for grayscale to my site, but I only need certain web elements to have them .

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can add custom tags in Html.

```
<customTag>Hello world</customTag>
```

But IE wont detect custom tags .
Just add this head of your document.

```
<script>document.createElement('customTag');</script>
```

The above example is a part of `html5shiv`.

This is one more [article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/adding-custom-tags-to-internet-explorer-the-official-way) which I found to for IE.

Comment: ...as long as you don't care if it's valid or if it's compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

No. A custom tag is not an HTML tag. If you use one your document stops being HTML.

Use the (semantically) most appropriate HTML element, then add attributes (generally `class`) to distinguish it for your script/stylesheet.