# HTML <false> markup

Tags: html

I found some code that uses this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <false>blah blah blah</false>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What is this? Is it an HTML5 creation? SO & Google searching `<false>` (with or without `HTML`) didn't show anything.

[This](http://syllabus.bos.nsw.edu.au/english/english-k10/content-and-outcomes/) is the site. Check the markup for `A. communicate through speaking, listening, reading, writing, viewing and representing*` under `Objective A`.

Comment: It's not a valid tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list

Comment: @Blender  I've added the URL reference. It's a major government site in Australia that's using it. (I know, it's just Australia, but still... :)

Comment: Well, governments don't have much authority over the HTML standard. The tag isn't a valid tag.

Comment: @Blender Sure, although that's not my point (as I suspect you know). The development team aren't hacks, so what's it doing there? :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing. That tag name isn't referenced in any of the CSS or JS files.

Comment: @Blender Hmm... maybe. Seems a little odd to have no purpose.

Comment: @Nick - I heard a story lately of a team that used the (then) non-standard attribute of 'translate' on some elements. It since got standardised and turned into a real head-ache, certainly not wise in retrospect. The Aust gov sites are usually pretty poor - as a recent instance, I've had a bunch of people telling me they've broken the gov services portal for Chrome in the past couple of months - previously working functionality (the ability to login) is now broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not defined in any HTML specification or public draft, and it is most probably not recognized as meaning anything in any browser. In short, it is a “custom tag”; cf. e.g. to [Using custom HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags).

In this case, the choice of the tag name looks very odd, and there does not seem to be any references to `false` element in the CSS or JavaScript code on the page. In general, however, custom tags could be used for styling and client-side scripting, since modern browsers normally parse elements marked up with custom tags and generate DOM nodes for them.

My guess is that the use of these tags is accidental, not intentional. The tags cause no problems as such, at least not until `<false>` markup is added to HTML... They apparently did not bother using a validator (the W3C validator reports 195 Errors, 26 warnings).

Answer (score 1):

`<false>` is not a valid HTML tag. However, some browser actually don't care and just parse unknown elements as inline elements, which is why you needed a reset CSS for IE≤7 (?) if you wanted to use new block level elements (e.g.  `<article>`).

This is considered bad style. Either prepare your own doctype or use CSS classes. There is no semantic tag to indicate false values.