# Is using custom HTML tags and replacing custom tags with outerHTML okay?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it alright to define and use custom tags? (that will not conflict with future html tags) - while replacing/rendering those by changing outerHTML??

I created a demo below and it seems to work fine

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="customtags">
        <c-TextField name="Username" ></c-TextField> <br/>
        <c-NameField name="name" id="c-NameField"></c-NameField> <br/>
        <c-TextArea name="description" ></c-TextArea> <br/>
        <blahblah c-t="d"></blahblah>
    </div>
    </body>


    <script>

    /* Code below to replace the cspa's with the actual html -- woaah it works well */    
        function ReplaceCustomTags() {
            // cspa is a random term-- doesn;t mean anything really
            var grs = $("*"); 
            $.each(grs, function(index, value) {
                var tg = value.tagName.toLowerCase();
                if(tg.indexOf("c-")==0) {
                    console.log(index);
                    console.log(value);
                    var obj = $(value);
                    var newhtml;
                    if(tg=="c-textfield") {
                        newhtml= '<input type="text" value="'+obj.attr('name')+'"></input>';
                    } else if(tg=="c-namefield") {
                        newhtml= '<input type="text" value="FirstName"></input><input type="text" value="LastName"></input>';
                    } else if(tg=="c-textarea") {
                        newhtml= '<textarea cols="20" rows="3">Some description from model</textarea>';
                    }
                    obj.context.outerHTML = newhtml;
                }


                z = obj;
            });
        }

        if(typeof(console)=='undefined' || console==null) { console={}; console.log=function(){}}

        $(document).ready(ReplaceCustomTags);
    </script>
    </html>
```

---

Update to the question:

Let me explain a bit further on this. Please assume that JavaScript is enabled on the browser - i.e application is not supposed to run without javascript.

> I have seen libraries that use custom attributes to define custom behavior in specified tags. For example Angular.js heavily uses custom attributes. (It also has examples on custom-tags). Although my question is not from a technical strategy perspective - I fail to understand why it would strategically cause problems in scalability/maintainability of the code.
>
> > Per me code like <ns:contact .....> is more readable than something like <div custom_type="contact" ....> . The only difference is that custom tags are ignored and not rendered, while the div type gets rendered by the browser
>
> Angular.js does show a custom-tag example (pane/tab). In my example above I am using outerHTML to replace these custom tags - whilst I donot see such code in the libraries - Am I doing something  shortsighted and wrong by using outerHTML to replace custom-tags?

Comment: I have looked for this question - and found many answers saying "its not html" and "it may conflict with future tags".  My question is more oriented in knowing if there could be serious technical limitation if I go with this approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom HTML Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags)

Comment: If you want to ask a question that is essentially different from the many existing questions on the same issue, you should formulate your question and its title to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with more details. I have previously gone through the "possible duplicate" and it does not address my concerns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a reason why you'd want to do this.

What would you think if you had to work on a project written by someone else who ignored all common practices and conventions? What would happen if they were no longer at the company to find out why they did something a certain way?

The fact that you have to just go through with JavaScript to make it work at all should be a giant red flag. Unless you have a VERY good reason to, do yourself a favor and use the preexisting tags. Six months from now, are you going to remember why you did things that way?

Comment: Thanks - but I fail to understand it strategically. We will need client-side-JS to make it work - Its a pretty large app and we want to keep UI rendering to the client. I checked with the recent browsers upto IE8 and it seems to work for us. Actually we did start with standard tags and custom attributes like &lt;div custom_type="contact" ....>   - put pretty soon found that its not so readable.

For me using custom tags this way will be the same as using a library like ExtJS where we write Ext.create('Ext.Panel').... The developer does not have to see what all HTML elements are created within

Comment: If it does work for you, and it is something that your company is adopting, then you have your "very good reason". Just be sure to document the hell out of your standards for this, and keep them up to date. Down the road, you don't want to wind up spending more time trying to figure the code out than it takes to fix a minor bug.

Answer (score 0):

It may well work, but it's probably not a good idea. Screen readers and search engines may have a hard/impossible time reading your page, since they may not interpret the JavaScript. While I can see the point, it's probably better to use this template to develop with, then "bake" it to HTML before putting it on the server.