# Will I run into problems if I use <div> instead of <p>?

Tags: html, dom

I'm working on a script that is programmatically formatting web content. Because the content is generated in a WYSIWYG editor that I have no control over, all new lines of text are exported as `<div>`s.

My very first gut reaction is DON'T DO THAT! But why? There's nothing exceptional about the `<p>` tag. I am concerned about any potential problem. I'd rather not waste the effort selectively adding `<p>`s in code if I don't have to.

This got me thinking...

- SEO: Will google hate me for it?
- Accessibility: Will screen readers die on this text or ignore it maybe?
- Fancy: Will double-tap to zoom break on mobile devices?

Similar but different: [Using custom HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags)

INB4 somebody complains about IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` tags do actually behave radically different than `div` tags, which is sadly beyond your control since this has to do with DOM parsing rather than CSS. Thankfully, you will most likely run into *less* problems with `div` tags than the former.

Even though `p` tags are block elements, they are defined to only be allowed to contain phrasing content. In reality, this means that they can only contain elements whose *default display type* is inline. Browsers will thus literally refuse to render e.g. `div` tags inside a `p` tag no matter what CSS you apply. `div` tags, however obviously don't have this restriction.

The only thing that I know of that differs to the favour of `p` tags, is that they don't require a closing tag if directly followed by one of a select few different tags (e.g. other `p` tags)

Other than that, there are no drawbacks in using `div` tags that I know of, and you are free to use whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

`div` tags will still let search engines index your text. Custom tags can be dangerous (especially on older browsers), but `div`s are widely supported. While there are some potential semantic differences, I doubt you would run into issues.