# Page break using CSS in HTML to create PDF

Tags: html, css

I have a custom tag `<PBR/>` in HTML and I want to break page in PDF from this tag through CSS. But I have no idea about this. How can I break pages:
I have tried this in CSS but it is not working --

```
pbr {
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

Comment: What other stylings does `pbr` have? We need more information

Comment: I have implemented this in html from where i have to break page.Then how can apply css on this? it is not any tag of html.i have write just for identification of page break.

Comment: Try changing it to a class like showdev said then applying that class to a `div` instead and tell us the result

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble comes in targeting [custom HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags) with CSS.
I suggest using a class instead:

```
.page { page-break-before:always; }
```

```
<pbr class="page" />
```

Comment: Did you try changing `<pbr>` to a `<div>` as suggested by Zeaklous?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class with the following properties and apply to your HTML element.

```
<style>
    .breakhere {
                page-break-after: always;
                display: block;
                clear: both;
            }
</style>

<div class="breakhere">...content...</div>
```

**Note:** Make sure your HTML doesn't contain overflow tag, as it will create problem with page-break tags.

Rotativa library provides a good option to return View as PDF.