# Why to use "class=" when I can use my own tag?

Tags: html, class, tags

I just wonder why should I use "class=" identificator instead of my own "tag"()?

[Class example](http://jsfiddle.net/ukg9K/)

```
 <span class="red"> Hello there! (using class)</span>
 .red {color: red;}
```

[Tag example](http://jsfiddle.net/6tva8/)

```
<div id="reddiv">
<red>Hello, there (using own tag)</red>    
</div>
#reddiv red {color: red;}
```

Its much more easier for me to use my own tags, since its faster to write.
Can you please tell me if doing it in first/second way has any negative/possitive sides?

Comment: I know nearly nothing of html and such, but I'd guess to support older / simpler browsers.

Comment: because that would not work on older browsers and is not valid html

Comment: Thanks for asnwer, if its the only problem then Iam fine with that.

Comment: @loqan, can I ask why? it's more data to transfer and less re-usability.

Comment: I am quite sure it is due to backward compatibility. In fact, some of the newer but valid tags introduced in HTML5 are not working well on older browsers.

Comment: As stated by @GertB. compliance with older browsers would be a problem. The main reason to use classes instead of custom tags or ids is that you may combine classes instead of having to create complete style sets for each tag. Example would be to have say a floated and red div which would be `<div class="floated red">`.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thats why I asked ;) I was just used to it and it is way faster to create own tags :P

Comment: just include your tags into a html5 shim for new html 5 elements and they will work in older browsers

Comment: and usability too, as many answer below. 
@loqan You should not want to reinvent the wheel. Your question is good though :)

Comment: Another aspect to look at is semantics. Tags shouldn't have a visual meaning but a semantic meaning, they should say something about the nature of the content. That's why tags like <b> (bold, a visual representation) were replaced with <strong> (meaning emphasised) and why tags like <nav>, <header> and <section> were introduced. This plays a big role with devices other than screens, like readers for the visually impaired where colors and fonts have little meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom HTML Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many advantages of using class.

1. First of all, with class, we use css styles which gives a lot more configuration options than simple HTML tags.
2. We give all the styles and formatting at one olace and just call the class everywhere we want to apply those, which in big projects like ERP, makes a big difference in code size.
3. The css style is more compatible with latest versions of browsers and a lot of old HTML formatting and style tags are deprecated in latest versions of HTML.
4. HTML tags behave differently under different browsers and different document modes. Where css will give same result everywhere.
5. The css classes can be applied to all the relevant tags on page at once just by defining it somewhere at the top of page.

Answer (score 3):

While this may work in most browsers, your HTML then loses context. When an application like a search engine (or screen readers or anything else that looks at the source) parses your document, what is it to make of a tag named 'red' or 'purple' or 'job'? It won't have context, so you'll lose out. HTML uses a set of predefined tags that have meaning, you can venture out of it but you'll lose the advantage of everyone instantly understanding (all or part) of your document.

If this document is part of a data transfer framework and not on the public web, you should look at XML.

Answer (score 1):

You should also not forget that predefined tags have a lot of default properties and your custom tags none. So you would need to define everthing over again for all elements apart from span. 
Also, you can have more than one class on an element, so `<span class="red bold">Red</span>` is possible.

Comment: Well it gets its properties from BODY. So I use the tags just for simple editing like right/left margin, font-weight and so on.

Comment: As u clearly see at my example it does. Body has the color and the size and because I want all the text on the page in this formating but just a little paragraph needs to be 200px off left I use own html tag to mark that part of text and use css for it.

this example shows it better http://jsfiddle.net/ukg9K/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove, change and swap between classes to change dynamical the element style or behavior, what you can't do with tags.
Tag is element that needs class to set it behavior and style.

Answer (score -1):

Custom elements are created using document.registerElement():

```
var reds = document.registerElement('red');
document.body.appendChild(new reds());
```

Comment: The question isn't asking about javascript in any way.

Comment: and you are gonna do that for every tag on the site? and what will this do in ie8?

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked.