# Limitations of customizing HTML tags and attributes with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been exploring with CSS and HTML this morning, and I'd like to know if there is any limitation while customizing HTML tags and attributes with CSS.

This example may help:

`<div class="app"></div>`

the style for the class app is:

`.app { background: black; }`

Now changing the HTML so the class is now an HTML tag and in the CSS, instead of creating a class, we change it to an HTML attribute like this:

HTML
`<app></app>`

CSS
`[app] { background: black; }`

Will this approach work cross-browser?, also, would the performance on the page load stay the same?

I've already tested with Chrome and Firefox and they work with no problem.

Comment: You cannot invent your own html tags. Stay with the known.

Comment: I don't think that's the developing direction for HTML, otherwise all the standard tags will become less valid, we may hardly understand others' HTML code, that's so terrible. BTW, HTML relates mostly to visual elements, not for data elements, so the purpose of custom tags doesn't help much and that's not some kind of limitation  (it's by design).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom HTML Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *may* work on most browsers, but creating custom tags is not supported in HTML. You may risk compatibility and possibly undefined behavior with some browsers. Not to mention this would also be bad for SEO, if that is a concern.

Stick with valid HTML tags, and use CSS classes to style them.