# html5 semantic tag for an article summary and highlight

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am looking for a proper html5 tag which I can use for marking summary of a very lengthy article. The summary itself can span for a paragraph or two.

I know there is a `<summary>` tag in html5 but this tag behaves in conjunction with `<details>` tag.

and secondly, I want to highlight a paragraph or two in the middle of a lengthly article. These highlighted section are important text that needs to be prominently displayed. Is there any html5 tag for this? or should I just use a class for highlighting? The point is, it's just not visual importance, but includes semantic importance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50096542/1066234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no block-level element for importance, and no element whatsoever for a summary (the `summary` element inside `details` is not really for a summary at all but rather a title of a kind).

In traditional HTML up to and including HTML 4.01 (and XHTML 1.0), `em` and `strong` indicate emphasis, but their definitions are very vague. In practice, they are little else than pseudo-semantic counterparts of italic and bolding, `i` and `b`. HTML5 makes the topic even more confusing by distinguishing between “stress emphasis” (which “changes the meaning of the sentence”) and “strong importance, seriousness, or urgency” without really defining the difference. In any case, `em` and `strong` are text-level (inline) markup, intended for individual words or short phrases rather than entire sentences, still less paragraphs or sequences of paragraphs.

The closest you can get is `<p><strong>...</strong></p>`, but it is questionable whether this is a good idea. It’s surely not the way `strong` is meant to be used, but it’s formally valid.

Thus, the practical approach is to use `div` elements (or maybe `p` elements) with a `class` attribute and suitable styling.

Comment: thanks Jukka for your valuable reply. So can I conclude saying there is no available markup for arbitrary block-level element intended for marking importance? I am currently using a `div` with class `summary` or `featured` as there are can be multiple paragraphs inside. I wanted to confirm if I doing this wisely or missing any best practices.

Comment: @krishworks, yes that is correct, and using `div` is OK.

Comment: @jukka-k-korpela just another follow up question, how about adding a new custom html5 tag for eg, <x-summary> or <x-highlight>? is there any downside of using these tags, except for the browser support for html5 custom tag? Thanks.

Comment: Using custom tags is usually not a good idea, see e.g. answers to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - "It’s surely not the way strong is meant to be used". I wonder about phrases like that. Meant by whom, exactly? You know how the HTML language design process works. If someone came up with a watertight case for using an emphasis element like that, are you seriously suggesting that a new element would be invented for the purpose? Or even that the semantic description of `<strong>` would need modifying to specifically allow it?

Comment: @Alohci, look at the examples in HTML specs and drafts—they use `strong` for short expressions, e.g. for the word “Warning” before warning text, rather than for the entire warning. And HTML5 CR explicitly says: “The strong element can be used in a heading, caption, or paragraph to distinguish the part that really matters from other parts [...].” I’m not suggesting anything about new elements or about changing any “semantic description”.

Comment: In the section on the strong element, last code example, first list item. `<strong>` wraps the entire contents of the paragraph. i.e. The entire warning. And the term "can be used" is permissive, giving a suggestion for use, not a limitation of use.

Comment: @Alohci, I read “can be used” as suggestive of typical use; a mere permission would be pointless (anything that is not forbidden is permitted). The last code example has *three words* in a `strong` element, so it’s really text-level markup rather than an element containing the text of a true paragraph.