# What is the correct HTML tag to emphasize a sentence or a section?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I realized that I was using `blockquote` throughout my HTML to emphasize paragraphs that have to be learned by my students – which is obviously wrong, since the `blockquote` is meant to specify a section that is quoted from another source.

In my case (mathematics), the paragraph(s) define(s) or describe(s) a word and should stand out visually.

After some research, I found the `em` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em) which "marks text that has stress emphasis", however, it seems to be designed for single words or a group of words, but not for paragraphs.

So the question is: What is the **correct HTML tag** to emphasize a complete sentence or a section (several paragraphs)?

Comment: What I found later: "No, there is no block-level element for importance (...) the practical approach is to use div elements (or maybe p elements) with a class attribute and suitable styling." - from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23466155/1066234

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, if you're defining something - and if fits with the structure of your document - you should look at `<dl>`: definition lists.

MDN has a page which explaiins what you need to know: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Within a `<dl>`, you have `<dt>` (definition term) and `<dd>`(definition description). `<dd>` is block-level, so can contain block-level elements such as paragraphs and lists, but `<dt>` is inline and should only contain other inline elements. If you're *really* keeping close to the rules :)

Example:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Stack Overflow</dt>
  <dd>
    A place that holds many answers, some of which are <em>mostly</em> correct.
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Most browsers will apply some indenting to definition lists by default, but that's about all you'll get out of the box in terms of styling. You'll need to apply your own styling rules to make them stand out more, but the variety of tags you get as part of a definition list should help you with that.

There's some discussion around the accessibility of definition lists for screen reader users, with different browsers and readers producing different results (see https://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=7089). This isn't optimal, but it seems that using definition lists isn't any worse than using unordered lists (`<ul>`); not an ideal solution (because one doesn't really exist), but not  the worst option.

Comment: This comes closer to an answer. However, `dl` stands for *list* and *needs both* `dt` and `dd`, e.g. for a glossary. Further, by my semantic understanding this would be like using `ul` with a `li` instead of a simple `p`aragraph... Your `because one doesn't really exist` seems to be the right answer. Maybe there will be something like `emblock` in the future.

Answer (score 1):

#### `dfn` element

If the content is important *because* it’s a definition (and all definitions are important in your document), you can use the [`dfn` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-dfn-element) and style the parent element accordingly.

```html
<p class="definition">definition of the <dfn>term</dfn></p>
```

The nearest ancestor `p` (or `li`, or `section`, or term-description group in a `dl`) has to define the term.

So if you have multiple paragraphs (like in the next example), the paragraphs without the `dfn` descendant are not semantically connected to the term/definition.

```html
<div class="definition">
  <p>paragraph about the term</p> <!-- semantically not part of the definition -->
  <p>definition of the <dfn>term</dfn></p>
  <p>another paragraph about the term</p> <!-- semantically not part of the definition -->
</div>
```

If the definition consists of multiple paragraphs, you can either use `section` or `dl` to convey that all these paragraphs contain the definition, but both alternatives aren’t always suitable.

#### `strong` element

If the content is important for other reasons (e.g., not every definition is important, or things other than definitions can be important, too), you can use the [`strong` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-strong). It conveys

> strong importance, seriousness, or urgency for its contents.

You can even convey the relative level of importance by using more `strong` elements:

```html
<p>sentence with an <strong>important part</strong></p>

<p>sentence with a <strong><strong>very important part</strong></strong></p>

<p><strong>important sentence with an <strong>especially important part</strong></strong></p>
```

As the `strong` element can only contain *phrasing content*, you can’t mark multiple paragraphs with one `strong` element.

---

If the content is important for other reasons, but happens to contain a definition, `dfn` and `strong` should be combined, of course.  And even if every definition is important, you may still use `strong` in addition, either to convey that definitions are important in this document, or to convey their relative importance.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to emphasize a text block which is not a definition, the usage of `dfn` would not be correct. `strong` is, as you state, not for paragraphs but would come the closest, reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) - and would suit if it could contain `p` tags! Seems that there is not yet a suitable HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is a group of DOM elements intended to add emphasis to the HTML content:

- strong
- b
- em
- i
- del
- strike

However, while semmantically, this will indicate emphasis, no screen reader (JAWS, Window Eyes, etc) will indicate so.

Comment: <b> and <i> are deprecated as they describe styling rather than structure. <del> and <strike> are also semantically different, they suggest that you should not pay attention to that content. This leaves <strong> and <em>, where <strong> would be "with vigour" and <em> would be "with emphasis".

Answer (score 0):

I will use strong tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong

> The  element is for content that is of "strong importance," including things of great seriousness or urgency (such as warnings). This could be a sentence that is of great importance to the whole page, or you could merely try to point out that some words are of greater importance compared to nearby content.