# Non-standard html tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

will Google penalize me for creating a non standard html tag? HTML is like XML and XML lets you make anything a tag so can I do the same in html?

```
<style>
    n{font-weight: normal;}
</style>


<b>Bold <n>Normal</n></b>
```

**Why?**

- Looks better (to me) than spans
- Looks better (to me) than span class="n"

Would Jquery find it faster?

```
$('n');
```

or

```
$('n.someclass');
```

As it would find **img** quickest, **#img** second and **.img** slowest.

Comment: Ask *one* question per question. Move the question about Google, or the question about speed, to a different question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags

Comment: Keeping in mind the [seo tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) notes about what is on topic, and that the correct approach for many questions about performance is "benchmark it yourself".

Comment: Note that if you do decide to use custom tags, there are "gotchas" on IE. You need to do what the html5shim folks did to make sure IE understands that those are elements. (The short version is just do `document.createElement('n')` in a script early on; you don't even have to save that element anywhere. That tells IE that `n` is an element tag.) You might also be interested in this: http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Comment: When it comes to Google everything is unclear, I was wondering if anyone has had previous experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No google will not penalise your site for using non standard html tags in Html document. But
When we talk about google, it is all about google bots and search engine results. When bots index or read your page it checks for type of document, based on type it crawl your site. Basically by using custom tags which are not standard as per doc type you are confusing those bots which may result in put less weightage on your content and may not show in search results.

2) It looks better to you. But you will have to think about cross browser compatibility too  after all you are writing it for the world. Some browser would render it in different way especially IE. So it is good to practice using standard Html tags.

3) In jquery, Selector concept is same for all elements. Again it might break in IE if use custom tags.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Google is not going to do anything about it.

And, I think that  would be faster, but there would not be much difference between the time taken by both.

Comment: How do you know, did you read it somewhere? Someone down voted you (wasn't me), people should explain why when they do that!

Comment: It is because 'n' is smaller than 'span', so when the browser would separate different words, it would separate n faster than span.