# <in a nutshell> as text not html tag

Tags: html

I have a text: `Our process<in a nutshell>`

that has an output as:

```
Our process<in nutshell="" a=""></in>
```

I didn't even know `in` is a tag and cannot find on google what it does.

How do I post it as text? And what is `<in>`?

Thanks!

Comment: `<in>` isn't a valid HTML tag.  Are you using anything like Bootstrap that may have customer tags?  As for having is display as text, replace '<' with '&lt;' and '>' with '&gt;'.

Comment: no. plain html. you can try it in the snippet here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<in>` tag defined in HTML, but browsers and other parsers still treat `<in a nutshell>` as tag. It creates an element node in the document tree, representing an unknown element, so it has only a set of general properties. It has no special rendering, and no functionality is associated with it. But you could style it and/or use client-side JavaScript to add functionality to it.

In this case, you didn’t mean to do anything like that, but the tag is still parsed, and `in` is treated as the element name (tag name) and `nutshell` and `a` as attribute names, with attribute values defaulted to the empty string. Since tags are treated as code for starting an element, the tag itself is not rendered. Browsers may imply a closing tag `</in>` under certain conditions. This explains the “output” presented in the question; it’s really just the fragment of code viewed in a browser’s Developer Tools. The actual rendering in the example case is just the string “Our process”.

To prevent this processing, the “<” character needs to be escaped somehow; `&lt;` is the best and most common method, so you would write

```
Our process&lt;in a nutshell>
```

There is no need to escape the “>”, but you may do so, for symmetry, using `&gt;`.

Comment: didn't know that you can create your own element node and apply properties to it. is there a situation when this is useful?

Comment: @Claudiu, it would often be useful, as it would help to make code shorter and more readable. However, there are a few reasons why it is generally not a good idea; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags

Answer (score 2):

In HTML:
    `Our process &lt;in a nutshell&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

< with <

and replace

```
> with &gt;
```

Does this give you the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

The browser is interpreting anything in '<>' as a tag.

You need to use the character code to display those symbols as text:

`Our process &lt;in a nutshell&gt;`

Comment: ok. I understand now, so `<lambada` will result in `<lambada></lambada>`. Thanks!