# CSS HTML Image with Text Overlay & Button

Tags: html, css, button, formatting

I'm a newbie to this stuff & I'm sure it's a simple enough fix, but I'm struggling to find a way to format TEXT over an IMAGE with a CSS Button - I really need this code to be responsive so it works on mobile devices also.

Any advice would be HUGELY appreciated.

Thanks All,

Johnny_P

Here's the CSS:

```
   /* SET Custom SQUARE CALL TO ACTION Button */

#ctasquare-button-container {
  text-align: center !important;
}

#ctasquare-button {
  text-align: center !important;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0 -115px;
    top:30;
  -webkit-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -moz-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -o-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  transition: .1s background-color linear;
  padding: 21px 35px;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-family: Futura-Pt;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ctasquare-button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -moz-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -o-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  transition: .1s background-color linear;
  color: black;
}
/* END Custom SQAURE CALL TO ACTION Button */
/* overlay text on image properties */

.sidebyside {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  /* for IE 6 */
}

textoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 50px;
  left:50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

h2.TitleBlock {
  font-color: #fff;
  font-size: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 30px 40px;

}
/* END overlay text on image properties */
```

And Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="sidebyside">

      <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/548c3773e4b0c5db6dc87107/t/559d66a4e4b0f2834cbd26d0/1436378788290/Surface-Sq-Left-Orange.png" width="480"; height="480"alt="ICT in Education" />

      <textoverlay>
       <h2 class="TitleBlock"><span style="color:white">My Awesome Title</span></h2>
        <h2>
          <font color="white">This is Where The Subtitle Goes. The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog</font>
        </h2>



<div class="ctasquare-button-container">
<a href="/xxx" id="ctasquare-button">Learn More
</a>
  &nbsp;
  <br><br>
</div>
</textoverlay>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is `<textoverlay>` a valid HTML tag or did you just make it up?

Comment: Custom HTML elements are allowed but [**Not Recommended**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags)

Comment: I just did this a couple weeks ago.  It was a pain.  Let me dig up the code and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks, The text works but the button get's cut off while viewing on mobile devices..... Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

For a start you could try this:

```css
   /* SET Custom SQUARE CALL TO ACTION Button */

#ctasquare-button-container {
  text-align: center !important;
}

#ctasquare-button {
  text-align: center !important;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0 -115px;
    top:30;
  -webkit-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -moz-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -o-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  transition: .1s background-color linear;
  padding: 21px 35px;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-family: Futura-Pt;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ctasquare-button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #b13f21;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -moz-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  -o-transition: .1s background-color linear;
  transition: .1s background-color linear;
  color: black;
}
/* END Custom SQAURE CALL TO ACTION Button */
/* overlay text on image properties */

.sidebyside {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  /* for IE 6 */
}

.sidebyside img{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

textoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

h2.TitleBlock {
  font-color: #fff;
  font-size: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 30px 40px;

}
/* END overlay text on image properties */
```

```html
<div>
<div class="sidebyside">

      <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/548c3773e4b0c5db6dc87107/t/559d66a4e4b0f2834cbd26d0/1436378788290/Surface-Sq-Left-Orange.png" width="480"; height="480"alt="ICT in Education" />

      <textoverlay>
       <h2 class="TitleBlock"><span style="color:white">My Awesome Title</span></h2>
        <h2>
          <font color="white">This is Where The Subtitle Goes. The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog</font>
        </h2>



<div class="ctasquare-button-container">
<a href="/xxx" id="ctasquare-button">Learn More
</a>
  &nbsp;
  <br><br>
</div>
</textoverlay>
</div>
</div>
```

To display sites correctly on other divices you need to implement media queries for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .sidebyside img{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried the modified code, but unfortunately, I get the same result on mobile devices. The problem occurs if viewing on a tablet or smartphone. The image appears with the text, but the button is no where to be seen. 

The image scales just enough to display the text, but the button is cut off the display.

This has been my main issue all along.

Any more ideas guys?