# How to override a ::after pseudo selector

Tags: css, html, ionic2

I have seen a number of posts similar to this, but I haven't found anything that works for me.

I have an Ionic2 application, where I have a style I want to get rid of.

This is what I can see..

[image]

and I wish to get rid of the background-image

It would be good to be able to do it using an Id (I only want this on this one element, and not others that may have these classes), but I have also tried the following...

```
.ion-header.header.header-md:after{
   background-image: none;
  }
```

I don't know why the following does not work.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to use `::after` ([CSS3 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after))? Also, are your styles loaded before or after the `main.css`?

Comment: `ion-header` is an element, not a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have 2 options:

1. Use `!important` rule.

```
.header-md:after,
tabbar:after,
.footer-md:after {
 background-image: none !important;
}
```

2. Override original styles.

```
.header-md:after,
.tabs-md[tabsPlacement="top"] > tabbar:after,
.footer-md:before,
.tabs-md[tabsPlacement="bottom"] > tabbar:after {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: The above worked perfectly. Also, I found as also mentioned `ion-header` is an element, not a class, so even `ion-header.header.header-md::after{
   background-image: none;  
}` actually worked.

Comment: Yes, but I don't recommend this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5970136/3258604