# Add color tags in css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a color tag in css that will change the color of text that is surrounded by it. like this:

```
<green>this is green</green>
```

Where the above text is green? I want to make these tags available for user input so that they can change the color of the text they are writing.

In my css file I have tried adding this:

```
green {
  color: green;
}
```

But when I try using the tag in the chat it does not work.

The only thing that I have been able to get work is adding this to the css:

```
span {
  color: green;
}
```

If I surround whatever text I want with `<span>` and `</span>` tags, that text displays as green.

But while this works, it isn't good enough because I want to implement other colors, and there is only one span tag, so this only gives me two color choices (the original color and green).

What is the proper way to do this?

I have also tried entering nothing into the css, and using something like this (in the chat line):

```
<span style="green">this is green</span>
```

But this also doesn't work.

Many thanks, I am really new to this part of web dev.

Comment: the proper way is to use CSS and classes

Comment: it would be `style="color:green"` - or you can add a class and define the color that way. Don't go making up rogue tags. You don't want to open that can of worms on yourself

Comment: @KaiQing do you mean as part of the span tag or as its own separate tag? I have tried both and neither one changed the font color

Comment: See [Using custom HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970093/using-custom-html-tags).

Comment: Note that in the long long time ago, there were presentational tags like `<font>`, `<small>`, and even `<blink>`. Those were done away with because it's generally a bad idea to use HTML to control how things look. It's better to use HTML to define what things are, and use CSS to control how they look. As a professional coder, I would be appalled if I saw someone created a `<green>` tag. This is not to say you are wrong to do this, especially if it's just for learning and fun; just a warning if/when you get into the professional realm :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create classes which will do basically what you are describing for example

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="pink">This is a pink heading</h1>

<p>This is some text this color is <span class="yellow">yellow</span>, this color is <span class="blue">blue</span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
.yellow{
   color: yellow;
}

.blue{
   color: blue;
}
.pink{
   color: pink;
}
```

Comment: If this answer has helped you, you can mark the answer as correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since html5 you can create custom elements. This will work (i'm sure about chrome and firefox)

```
<style>
  green {
    color: green;
  }
  red {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<green>Green text</green>
<red>Red text</red>
```

Use the inspector in the browser, to find out, whats wrong with your style definition or html.

Comment: This is generally not best practice, seeing as it isnt 100% browser compatible